# Adding buffer type to "New buffer in mode"

Tags: emacs, aquamacs, oz

When I choose the option "New buffer in mode" I'd like to open a buffer for an obscure programming language called oz. At the moment it is not in the list of buffer modes to choose from.

I have the needed software available (Mozart interpreter.)

Have searched valiantly and if this is in a doc somewhere I have not been able to find it.

Ps. I am using aquamacs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.eecs.ucf.edu/~leavens/COP4020/running_oz.shtml has instructions for what to add to your `.emacs` file in order to enable `oz-mode`. It seems to assume that `oz-mode.el` is installed in Emacs' `load-path` already.

Here's my original answer text; I'm leaving it here for the general case.

The list if modes is really a list of Emacs Lisp programs installed on your site. Unless you have an Emacs Lisp program telling Emacs how to indent, comment, etc in this language, Emacs does not have a dedicated mode to offer. You can get by fine with Fundamental mode or Text mode, though, but there won't be any help for indenting, syntax highlighting, etc.

All things counted, if you are at all familiar with Emacs, it's usually not very hard to create your own mode, especially if you can build on an existing mode for a similar language.

Comment: Thanks. I see now that my googling was fruitless because I did not know the terminology. Hoping this will be useful to some others as oz might be their first foray into emacs.

Comment: @tripleee The link give 404. If you could please update it.

Comment: I have no real knowledge of this system. Their current web pages appear to be at http://mozart.github.io/